# Can you make Windows 7 not localize folder names?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, localization

I am running preinstalled Windows 7 Home Premium (Nordic, in Finnish for me). My `C:\` folder of course has the `Users` folder, but its name is in Finnish.

[image: Folder name]

Clicking on the folder name in Explorer shows the real name.

[image: Real folder name]

This one is also the one showed by other applications, like the Web browser or 7-Zip.

This is not limited to `C:\Users` but also applies to `Start Menu` etc.

**What I'd like to do is to turn off this localization in Explorer. Is there a way to do this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable LocalizedResourceName (desktop.ini) globally?](http://superuser.com/questions/788555/is-there-a-way-to-disable-localizedresourcename-desktop-ini-globally)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Folder customization

> Folders are normally displayed with the standard folder icon. A common use of the `Desktop.ini` file is to assign a custom icon or thumbnail image to a folder. You can also use `Desktop.ini` to create an infotip that displays information about the folder and controls some aspects of the folder's behavior, such as specifying localized names for the folder or items in the folder.
>
> <sub>Source: [How to Customize Folders with Desktop.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>
>
> Before the shell displays the name of a directory, the shell looks for a `Desktop.ini` file. If it finds one, it displays a redirected name obtained from `LocalizedReourceName` to the end user.
>
> <sub>Source: [Customizing Folders with Desktop.ini (Windows CE 5.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906608.aspx)</sub>

Here's the default content of the `desktop.ini` file stored in the `C:\Users` folder:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21813
```

### Disabling localized names

Windows Explorer doesn't seem to provide any documented way to ignore folder localization, but removing the `LocalizedResourceName` line does the job. While you could also delete the file entirely, it's not a good idea as you would lose other customization settings such as icons or tooltips.

### Batch automation

Below there's a simple batch script which can do that for you, recursively scanning every folder in the system drive. Make sure to run it as administrator.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

pushd "%systemdrive%\"

for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /a /b /s desktop.ini') do (
find /i "LocalizedResourceName=" "%%~G" >nul
if !errorlevel! == 0 (
takeown /f "%%~G" /a >nul
icacls "%%~G" /grant:r *S-1-5-32-544:F /q >nul
attrib -h -s "%%~G"
type "%%~G" | findstr /i /v /c:"LocalizedResourceName=" > "%%~G.new"
copy "%%~G" "%%~nxG.bak" >nul 2>&1
del /a "%%~G"
ren "%%~G.new" "%%~nxG"
attrib +h +s "%%~G.bak"
attrib +h +s "%%~G"
))

popd
pause & exit /b
```

Comment: thank you sir, you really save my day, I couldn't stand the inconsistency of my folders name

Comment: Wouldn't it be even better to comment the line out with `;`?

Comment: Any idea what are the `stringID` definitions?

Answer (score 2):

The translation is controlled by a hidden file called `desktop.ini`. Open the Windows Explorer options, make sure you activate the option to show hidden and system files, now go into the folders, where you don't want to have a translation, and delete the ini file.

Comment: If you delete the entire `desktop.ini` file, other customisation settings such as icons or tooltips will also be lost.