# Is there a way to disable LocalizedResourceName (desktop.ini) globally?

Tags: windows-7, desktop.ini

I'm using a German windows 7 and while I'm fine with that (otherwise I'd install an english version), I really dislike localized folder names - I'd like to see the true folder name.

Of course I could simply delete `LocalizedResourceName` from every single `desktop.ini` but I wonder if there's some registry setting that simply causes Windows to ignore the localized names.

Comment: No, there's no related registry setting. If you want non-localized names, you'll need to either comment out or delete the `LocalizedResourceName` line from each file. You might want to remove all `LocalizedFileNames` sections, too.

Comment: This single issue is a valid reason to avoid anything but English in my opinion. Another reason is Excel changing e.g. "=CONCATENATE()" into "=SAMMANFOGA()" _(Swedish, all others also changed in similar fashion)_.

Comment: I know @Hannu, but the system is for my father who dislike anglicisms and wouldn't want an english Windows. Luckily he doesn't use Excel either.

Comment: =) language is a barrier at times, making things harder - not only in one way.

Comment: I wish someone had a solution...

Comment: @Kiwy Mayhaps I [can](http://superuser.com/a/816065/35237) grant your wish. Partially at least...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you make Windows 7 not localize folder names?](http://superuser.com/questions/739631/can-you-make-windows-7-not-localize-folder-names)

Answer (score 5):

- As a workaround, note that if you click in the address bar, the full non-translated path displays there
- In order to get rid of the `LocalizedResourceName` automatically, install a `bash` (e.g. from [git](http://git-scm.com/download/win)) and run
  `for desktopini in $(find /c/Users -name desktop.ini); do
     sed -i "/^LocalizedResourceName/d" $desktopini;
  done`
  If you want to merely comment the entry for later reversal, use
  [`"s/^\(LocalizedResourceName\)/;\1/"`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4) instead of
  `"/^LocalizedResourceName/d"`.
  Of course you can modify the path `/c/Users` to whatever path desired, just remember that msys/mingw uses forward slashes and not colon after the drive letter.
- The might be a similar way using powershell, but I never bothered learning that since I use bash anyway... [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6028937/321973) might yield a good start for the `sed` part. Or you just check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/741227/35237) from a basically duplicate question
- finally, note that `desktop.ini` is completely ignored if a folder doesn't have either the system or readonly attribute set

Comment: Note that sed is not actually part of bash.  However, I doubt there are many ways to instal bash that don't also get you sed installed ...

Comment: @SamB good point, but at least msys/mingw and cygwin, the two most likely sources of a windows bash do IIRC include sed by default

Comment: almost certainly in any configuration that includes bash, yes.  Which for Cygwin or MSYS would be any configuration.

Comment: This might fail as often the file is in UTF-16 encoding, while Cygwin/MSYS Bash can only handle UTF-8 (or whatever your terminal has been set to.) You can `cat desktop.ini | iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8` and then operate on a copy, and then convert it back.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative **PowerShell** approach to comment out the **LocalizedResourceName** statement in *desktop.ini* files:

```
$LRN = 'LocalizedResourceName'
gci desktop.ini -Hidden -Recurse -ea silent | ForEach{
    $Content = Get-Content $_ -raw
    If ( $Content -match $LRN ) {
        $Content -replace $LRN, ";$LRN" | Set-Content $_ -force
    }
}
```

To create an undo script, just swap the `-replace` parameters:

```
$Content -replace ";$LRN", $LRN
```

Comment: You have a typo in your italic _desktop.ini_ file name. I can't edit by myself, because I have to change 6 characters at least...

Comment: Done. It was only two characdters: `ks -> sk`. I seem to have dyslexic fingers.

Comment: You probably need to run this as admin.

Comment: Strangely, this one is ~10 slower than using: `gci -Recurse -Hidden -Force . | where { $_.Name -eq "desktop.ini" }`

Comment: Scanning my system I also noticed that: **(a)** Not all files are encoded correctly as `UTF-16 LE`, and you need to use `Set-Content -Encoding unicode`, and that **(b)**, many files are also called `Desktop.ini`, with capital `D`. Not sure what is the implication of this.

Comment: The case of the name doesn't matter. Files encoded as UTF-8 are functional -- Unicode/UTF-16 LE encoding would only be needed if required for characters used in `LocalizedResourceName`, `InfoTip`, or `[LocalizedFileNames]`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone prefering the powershell way, this script worked for me:

```
$desktopinis = gci -Recurse -Hidden . | where { $_.Name -eq "desktop.ini" }

foreach ($ini in $desktopinis) {

    $content = $ini | get-content
    foreach ($line in $content) {
        if ($line -cmatch "^LocalizedResourceName=") {

            $newname = $line.substring(22) # propertyname plus one for the equals sign

            $before = $ini.Directory.FullName
            $after  = $ini.Directory.Parent.FullName + "\" + $newname

            Write-Host ("Renaming '" + $before + "' to '" + $after + "'.")

            Move-Item -Path $before -Destination $after
            Remove-Item -Path ($after + "\desktop.ini") -Force
        }
    }
}
```

It looks for desktop ini files recursively in the current folder and renames directories that contain them and where they contain a LocalizedResourceName to their shown name, then deletes the desktop ini file.

The output should be sufficient to revert what was done if anything goes sideways.

Without warranty.