# Always display actual path instead of translation

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When using windows 7 in a language other than english (german in my case) the paths (mainly of the system folders, like `Program Files` for instance) in the windows-explorer are sometimes translated:

[image]

Is there a way to disable this translation and always show the *actual* names of the folders?

These translations are annoying when you have to set up programs manually or generally when programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you make Windows 7 not localize folder names?](http://superuser.com/questions/739631/can-you-make-windows-7-not-localize-folder-names)